Actualizar datos de un Excel en Python
Hola me encuentro realizando un código en el cual genere un Excel con los URLs y titulo de los productos con los que cuenta la pagina web a continuación:
https://tejano.com.ar/anticipo-ss25/
Este es el link del Excel:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3CJezyXs4vB_kEzzDOMEmpWupVbyYKjlseDncX7C74/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Ahora tengo que ir actualizando los datos del Excel a medida que se van agregando o quitando los productos de la pagina web es decir:
Los nuevos productos se agregan al Excel y se pintan con amarillo.
Los productos eliminados se pintan con rojo.
Los productos actuales se pintan con celeste a modo de comprobación
Entonces convertí el Excel en una API mediante sheetdb y realice el siguiente codigo en python:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Configura las URLs
web_url = "https://tejano.com.ar/anticipo-ss25/"
sheetdb_url = "https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/nfenif9l1mmve"  # Reemplaza con tu URL de API de SheetDB

# Colores para marcar las celdas
yellow_fill = "FFFF00"  # Amarillo
red_fill = "FF0000"     # Rojo
blue_fill = "00FFFF"    # Celeste

# Función para obtener productos de la web
def get_web_products(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    product_elements = soup.select('h1.h2.h3.js-product-name.mb-3')
    return {prod.text.strip().lower(): prod.find_parent('a')['href'] for prod in product_elements}

# Función para obtener productos de SheetDB
def get_sheetdb_products(api_url):
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    return response.json()

# Función para actualizar productos en SheetDB
def update_sheetdb(api_url, updates):
    for update in updates:
        requests.put(api_url, json=update)

# Obtener productos de la web
web_products = get_web_products(web_url)

# Obtener productos actuales de la hoja de cálculo
sheetdb_data = get_sheetdb_products(sheetdb_url)

# Crear un diccionario con el nombre del producto como clave, normalizando nombres
sheetdb_products = {entry['TITULO'].strip().lower(): entry for entry in sheetdb_data}

# Determinar cambios
new_products = {name: url for name, url in web_products.items() if name not in sheetdb_products}
removed_products = {name: sheetdb_products[name] for name in sheetdb_products if name not in web_products}
current_products = {name: url for name, url in web_products.items() if name in sheetdb_products}

# Imprimir resultados de depuración
print("Productos de la web (normalizados):")
for name, url in web_products.items():
    print(f"{name}: {url}")

print("\nDatos obtenidos de SheetDB (normalizados):")
for name, entry in sheetdb_products.items():
    print(f"{name}: {entry['URL']}")

# Preparar actualizaciones
updates = []
for name, url in new_products.items():
    updates.append({
        "TITULO": name,
        "URL": url,
        "color": yellow_fill  # Marcar como nuevo
    })
for name, entry in removed_products.items():
    updates.append({
        "TITULO": name,
        "URL": entry['URL'],
        "color": red_fill  # Marcar como eliminado
    })
for name, url in current_products.items():
    updates.append({
        "TITULO": name,
        "URL": url,
        "color": blue_fill  # Marcar como existente
    })

# Actualizar la hoja de cálculo en SheetDB
update_sheetdb(sheetdb_url, updates)

# Imprimir resumen
print(f"\nNuevos productos agregados: {len(new_products)}")
print(f"Productos eliminados: {len(removed_products)}")
print(f"Productos existentes actualizados: {len(current_products)}")

El problema es que toma todos los productos como eliminados cuando deberian ser existentes:
Nuevos productos agregados: 0
Productos eliminados: 48
Productos existentes actualizados: 0

¿Por qué mejor no trabajas con una base de datos, aunque sea SQLite, y los cambios los vas reflejando en un archivo de Excel nuevo, que se irá creando de cero cada vez que hay cambios? Digo yo que es más sencillo manejar estados (nuevo, modificado, eliminado) e inventario en la BD con las columnas correspondientes; y finalmente hacer un "dump" de eso a un archivo externo (json, xml, o xlsx en tu caso).

por lo que veo es que no trae los productos
que te parese esta modificacion:
def get_web_products(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    parent = soup.find("div", {"class": "js-product-table row row-grid"})
    return { x.find('a')['title'].strip() : x.find('a')['href'] for x in parent.find_all("div",{"class","item"})}


Realice dicha modificación y esto obtengo como resultado:
Nuevos productos agregados: 48
Productos eliminados: 48
Productos existentes actualizados: 0
Ahora trae los productos pero los sigue marcando como eliminados y debe ser existentes

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Configura las URLs
web_url = "https://tejano.com.ar/anticipo-ss25/"
sheetdb_url = "https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/nfenif9l1mmve"  # Reemplaza con tu URL de API de SheetDB

# Colores para marcar las celdas
yellow_fill = "FFFF00"  # Amarillo
red_fill = "FF0000"     # Rojo
blue_fill = "00FFFF"    # Celeste

# Función para obtener productos de la web
def get_web_products(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    parent = soup.find("div", {"class": "js-product-table row row-grid"})
    return {x.find('a')['title'].strip().lower(): x.find('a')['href'] for x in parent.find_all("div", {"class": "item"})}

# Función para obtener productos de SheetDB
def get_sheetdb_products(api_url):
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    return response.json()

# Función para actualizar productos en SheetDB
def update_sheetdb(api_url, updates):
    for update in updates:
        requests.put(api_url, json=update)

# Obtener productos de la web
web_products = get_web_products(web_url)

# Obtener productos actuales de la hoja de cálculo
sheetdb_data = get_sheetdb_products(sheetdb_url)

# Crear un diccionario con el nombre del producto como clave, normalizando nombres
sheetdb_products = {entry['TITULO'].strip().lower(): entry for entry in sheetdb_data}

# Normalizar productos de la web
web_products_normalized = {name.lower(): url for name, url in web_products.items()}

# Determinar cambios
new_products = {name: url for name, url in web_products_normalized.items() if name not in sheetdb_products}
removed_products = {name: sheetdb_products[name] for name in sheetdb_products if name not in web_products_normalized}
current_products = {name: url for name, url in web_products_normalized.items() if name in sheetdb_products}

# Imprimir resultados de depuración
print("Productos de la web:")
for name, url in web_products.items():
    print(f"{name}: {url}")

print("\nDatos obtenidos de SheetDB:")
for entry in sheetdb_data:
    print(f"{entry['TITULO']}: {entry['URL']}")

print("\nProductos actuales detectados:")
for name, url in current_products.items():
    print(f"{name}: {url}")

# Preparar actualizaciones
updates = []
for name, url in new_products.items():
    updates.append({
        "TITULO": name,
        "URL": url,
        "color": yellow_fill  # Marcar como nuevo
    })
for name, entry in removed_products.items():
    updates.append({
        "TITULO": name,
        "URL": entry['URL'],
        "color": red_fill  # Marcar como eliminado
    })
for name, url in current_products.items():
    updates.append({
        "TITULO": name,
        "URL": url,
        "color": blue_fill  # Marcar como existente
    })

# Imprimir actualizaciones
print("\nActualizaciones que se enviarán a SheetDB:")
for update in updates:
    print(update)

# Actualizar la hoja de cálculo en SheetDB
update_sheetdb(sheetdb_url, updates)

# Imprimir resumen
print(f"\nNuevos productos agregados: {len(new_products)}")
print(f"Productos eliminados: {len(removed_products)}")
print(f"Productos existentes actualizados: {len(current_products)}")

Le hice unas modificaciones al script y ahora solo 1 producto lo esta tomando como eliminado y nuevo es decir:
Nuevos productos agregados: 1
Productos eliminados: 1
Productos existentes actualizados: 47

Por favor use la sección respuestas solo si tenes una respuesta. Deberias modificar tu pregunta añadiendo esta informacion, usando el boton editar debajo de tu publicación
